# A way to burn a multiple windows

Tags: windows, burning

I want to ask if it is possible to burn multiple different windows in one DVD example a windows 7 and windows 8.1 in the same DVD
Thanks.

Comment: x64 Windows ISOs are a bit bigger than 3 GB, and regular DVDs are 4.5 GB, so two versions of Windows won't fit on it. You could try double-layer DVDs though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Check out the [YUMI- Multiboot project](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/).

A DVD most likely won't have sufficient space for multiple installations, however you can use a USB stick and put multiple operating systems on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be possible with the right software.  These steps [guide](http://www.theeldergeek.com/windows_7/custom_w7_installation_dvd.htm) you through burning multiple Windows 7 versions on a DVD.  However, I dont see why it wouldnt work with Windows 8 as well.